# How to find out distance using camera in iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, camera

Is there any way to find out the distance using camera from focused point in iphone?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice

This API, seems that the only supported actions are: - check if AF is supported on the device, enable/disable AF, set the point-of-interest that is NOT the distance, but only a point in the camera view.

Certainly not what you want to do.

Might be supported in private API... but that would not pass the validation process (App gets rejected on use of private API').